# How to get matching element from array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

trying to get below expected result but its not going in for of loop of `specialtyMembers` any idea how to get expected response matching two arrays , Any apporach to use filter ?

main.js

```
const members = [{
    "indexId": "1",
    "planId": "8304TDMACC001"
}]

const specialtyMembers = [{
        "proxyId": "",
        "internalID": "38482099",
        "externalID": "",
        "indexID": "1",
        "gender": "Male"
    },
    {
        "proxyId": "",
        "internalID": "38482100",
        "externalID": "",
        "indexID": "2",
        "gender": "Female"
    }
]

if (members) {
    const membersArray: any = [];
    for (const member of members) {
        if (specialtyMembers) {
            for (const cacheMember of specialtyMembers) {
                if (member.indexId === cacheMember.indexID) {
                    membersArray.push(cacheMember);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    specialtyMembers = membersArray;
}
```

expected output because indexId only matches with this

```
 [{
        "proxyId": "",
        "internalID": "38482099",
        "externalID": "",
        "indexID": "1",
        "gender": "Male"
    }
]
```

Comment: What are you expecting?

Comment: i added expected result in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `filter` through the `specialtyMembers` array like so:

```
specialtyMembers = specialtyMembers.filter(e => members[0].indexId == e.indexID);
```

Note: you will have to change `specialtyMembers` from a constant to a variable. To do that, change `const` to `var` in this line:

```
var specialtyMembers = [{...}, {...}];
```

Demonstration:

```js
const members = [{
  "indexId": "1",
  "planId": "8304TDMACC001"
}];

var specialtyMembers = [{
    "proxyId": "",
    "internalID": "38482099",
    "externalID": "",
    "indexID": "1",
    "gender": "Male"
  },
  {
    "proxyId": "",
    "internalID": "38482100",
    "externalID": "",
    "indexID": "2",
    "gender": "Female"
  }
];

specialtyMembers = specialtyMembers.filter(e => members[0].indexId == e.indexID);

console.log(specialtyMembers);
```

## EDIT:

If there are multiple elements in `members`, you just need to make an array of the `indexId`s like so:

```
var indexIds = members.map(e => e.indexId);
```

Then change the `filter` statement to this:

```
specialtyMembers = specialtyMembers.filter(e => indexIds.includes(e.indexID));
```

Demonstration:

```js
const members = [{
  "indexId": "1",
  "planId": "8304TDMACC001"
}];

var specialtyMembers = [{
    "proxyId": "",
    "internalID": "38482099",
    "externalID": "",
    "indexID": "1",
    "gender": "Male"
  },
  {
    "proxyId": "",
    "internalID": "38482100",
    "externalID": "",
    "indexID": "2",
    "gender": "Female"
  }
];

var indexIds = members.map(e => e.indexId);

specialtyMembers = specialtyMembers.filter(e => indexIds.includes(e.indexID));

console.log(specialtyMembers);
```

Comment: if we have multiple elements in members how we would match you are checking first element

Comment: Oh, so you want to check if any members in `specialtyMembers` have the same ID as any member in `members`? I'll edit my answer

Comment: yes thats correct trying to filter specialtyMembers array based on members array

Comment: Fixed @hussain, any better?

Comment: `{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: indexIds.indcludes is not a function",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 36,
  "colno": 58
}`

Comment: I fixed it, it was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use `reduce` to create a new array with only elements which pass in your condition, using `filter`:

```
specialtyMembers = members.reduce((acc, ele) => {
    const filteredArr = specialtyMembers.filter(x => ele.indexId === x.indexID)
    return filteredArr.length > 0 ? acc.concat(filteredArr) : acc;
}, [])
```

Comment: no, it will not. in the end members and specialtyMembers will stay intact

Comment: but i want to return specialtyMembers after filter

Comment: ah, I see, so you can bind it back to `specialtyMembers`, but you have to change `const` to `let` or `var`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const members = [{
  "indexId": "1",
  "planId": "8304TDMACC001"
}]

const specialtyMembers = [{
    "proxyId": "",
    "internalID": "38482099",
    "externalID": "",
    "indexID": "1",
    "gender": "Male"
  },
  {
    "proxyId": "",
    "internalID": "38482100",
    "externalID": "",
    "indexID": "2",
    "gender": "Female"
  }
]


if (members) {
  let memberIndexes = new Set(members.map(m => m.indexId))

  let result = specialtyMembers ? specialtyMembers.filter(m => memberIndexes.has(m.indexID)) : []
  console.log(result)

}
```